# How do you set a custom message or a json in the succcess output of a Azure Data Factory pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

There is a rest API to query the status of a pipeline and when the pipeline completes all you get is a single value in a Json that says 'Success' . How do you append additional data to this message.

I have not tried as I dont have an idea.

So there is a Failure Activity for instance . You can set the flow to a Fail Activity and it allows to set a custom message in the error status of the pipeline. Similarly I dont see anything for success.

Comment: Try to provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: I judt did . Gave an example of Fail Activity.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a rest API to query the status of a pipeline and when the pipeline completes all you get is a single value in a Json that says 'Success' . How do you append additional data to this message.**

To achieve your scenario, we have the only option is to use set variable activity.  here you can append additional data to output of web activity.

- Here I created **response** variable with `string` type and passed value as `@concat('Pipeline status is',activity('Web1').output.response)` it will give you output as **Pipeline status is Success.**
  [image]

> Fail Activity is the activity in Azure Data Factory use to purposefully fail the pipeline along with sending the custom error code and error message with it. there is no such thig for success.

Comment: This will go in the output. I am aware of this.  I don't think you can add additional variables  OR format the message field, in the JSON that you get while querying the status of a pipeline run.

Comment: I believe success/failure is representing a boolean (true/false), so that means your goal of adding text to a boolean is never going to work.  You do not modify Azure functions behavior like this.  If you want custom data returned then you need to save it to your own calculated column, variable, or whatever.

Comment: @zokolot - Please understand 'message' is a string field in the pipeline run response Json.  Please understand before commenting.